# Issue while writing to serial port on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, serial-port, boost-asio, macos-mojave

**Background**

I am trying to write/print to a serial port on MacOS Mojave. Serial port is connected to a thermal printer with ESC/POS emulation. I have used `boost::asio::serial_port` from `boost 1.67.0` for this task. See the following code:

```
#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL -1

#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::serial_port port( io );

    std::string portname="/dev/tty.usbserial-12";

    try{
        port.open(portname.c_str(), ec);

        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "error : port.open() failed... portname=" << portname << ", e=" << ec.message().c_str() << std::endl; 
            return FAIL;
        }
        port.set_option( boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate( 19200 ) );

        unsigned char init[2] = { 27, 64 };
        unsigned char hello[6] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
        unsigned char cut[2] = { 29, 86 };

        boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer(init, sizeof(init)));
        boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer(hello, sizeof(hello)));
        boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer(cut, sizeof(cut)));

        port.close();
        return SUCCESS;
    }catch(...){
        return FAIL;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I tried to use FileDescriptor as in the following snippet:

```
int fd; //Descriptor for the port
fd = open("/dev/tty.usbserial-12", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (fd == -1) {
    std::cout << "Unable to open port. \n";
    return FAIL;
}

struct termios options;

tcgetattr(fd, &options);
cfsetispeed(&options, B19200);
cfsetospeed(&options, B19200);

options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

std::cout << "Port configured.\n";

unsigned char init[2] = { 27, 64 };
unsigned char hello[6] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
unsigned char cut[2] = { 29, 86};

int rv = FAIL;

rv = write(fd, init, 2);
if(rv<SUCCESS){
    std::cout << "could not write" << std::endl;
    return FAIL;
}

rv = write(fd, "hello\n", 6);
if(rv<SUCCESS){
    std::cout << "could not write" << std::endl;
    return FAIL;
}

rv = write(fd, cut, 2);
if(rv<SUCCESS){
    std::cout << "could not write" << std::endl;
    return FAIL;
}

std::cout << "closing FD" << std::endl;
close(fd);
return SUCCESS;
```

Console output of previous snippet:

```
Port configured.
closing FD
```

Unfortunately, *there is no error and no output at device side*.

**EDIT 1 END**

I can confirm that MacOS picks up connected serial port by checking output of `ls /dev/tty.usbserial*` and `ls /dev/cu.usbserial*` before and after connecting it to my Mac.

Also, if I run `screen /dev/tty.usbserial-12 19200` then run my app I get an error stating that `resource busy`.

While searching online I came across a [`SimpleSerial`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjB1c3fmOrdAhUHWSwKHZaTCKUQFjAGegQIARAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmicrofluidics.utoronto.ca%2Ftrac%2Fdropbot%2Fexport%2F8394ef23b9b9c60bd9df913ce9b49c4f133efc5e%2Fdmf_control_board_software%2FSimpleSerial.cpp&usg=AOvVaw1HvS0YYWj4hV1KeqeAOemw) implementation with the following comment written at top of file:

> IMPORTANT:
>   On Mac OS X boost asio's serial ports have bugs, and the usual implementation
>   of this class does not work. So a workaround class was written temporarily,
>   until asio (hopefully) will fix Mac compatibility for serial ports.
>   Please note that unlike said in the documentation on OS X until asio will
>   be fixed serial port *writes* are *not* asynchronous, but at least
>   asynchronous *read* works.
>   In addition the serial port open ignores the following options: parity,
>   character size, flow, stop bits, and defaults to 8N1 format.
>   I know it is bad but at least it's better than nothing.

I tried to search online in order to confirm that there is a known bug but couldn't find a relevant one.

**Issue**

The code above executes without any error but, for reasons unknown to me, *there is no output at printer*. I can "print" using `screen /dev/tty.usbserial-12 19200`.

Same code does work on Raspberry PI running raspbian and produces desired output at printer.

**Questions**

Is there anything wrong with my code? Have I missed some steps along the way? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You know there's a bug in Boost.asio, so you want to know how to work around that? You need to compare the actual system calls being made when `screen` writes to the device, and when Boost.asio writes to the device. You can run them both under `strace` for a start, and turn up detailed logging of buffer contents, ioctl calls, etc.

Comment: @Useless I don't know if there is a bug as there is no evidence provided at linked file. My web search did not result in any open bug issue either.

Comment: **You** quoted a file saying _boost asio's serial ports have bugs_. And, I've told you how to see what screen is doing differently.